# Waiting for finish reading a data in javascript

Tags: javascript, file, d3.js

I am using d3.js to read data from a tsv file,but I found that there is something strange in the procedure,I read the data and push each line into an array called dataset and then want to calculate the variable total by using a for loop,but it seems to fail(there is no any datum in dataset),maybe it is because the javascript just going on without waiting for finish reading the file.The code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>THis is a te</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="fun.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            var dataset = new Array();
            var parseDate = d3.time.format('%Y-%b-%e').parse;
            d3.tsv("data.tsv",function(error,data){
                    for(var i in data){

                        //console.log(data[i].date);
                        //console.log(parseDate(data[i].date));
                        var elapse = (i == 0) ? 0 : dateElapse(parseDate(data[i-1].date),parseDate(data[i].date));
                        dataset.push({
                                date : parseDate(data[i].date),
                                state : data[i].state,
                                elapse : elapse
                            });
                    }
                });

            var total = 0;

            for(var i in dataset){
                total =total + dataset[i].elapse;
            }

            console.log(total);


            var tau = Math.PI * 2;
            var width = 960,height = 500;
            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr({
                        "width" : width,
                        "height": height,
                    });

            var container = svg.append("g").attr({
                        "transform":"translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2+ ")"
                    });


            var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                        .innerRadius(180)
                        .outerRadius(240)
                        .startAngle(0);

            var background = container.append("path")
                                .datum({endAngle: tau})
                                .style("fill","#ddd")
                                .attr("d",arc)

            var foreground = container.append("g").append("path")
                                .datum({endAngle: 0.25 * tau})
                                .style("fill","#ffa500")
                                .attr("d",arc)  



        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

fun.js：

```
var month = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
var millseconds_per_day = 86400000;

function getDateParser(specifier) {
    return d3.time.format(specifier).parse;
}

function day( ) {
    return this.getDate();
}

function month() {
    return this.getMonth();
}

function year( ) {
    return this.getFullYear();
}


function dateElapse(start,end) {
    return Math.ceil((end - start) / millseconds_per_day);
}

function loadtsv(file,arr){
    arr = new Array();

    d3.tsv(file,function(error,data){
        var parser = getDateParser("%Y-%b-%e"); 

        for(var i in data){
            var elapse = (i == 0) ? 0 : dataElapse(parser(data[i-1].date,parser(data[i].data)));

            arr.push({
                date : parser(data[i].data),
                state: data[i].state,
                elapse : elapse
            })
        }

    });
}
```

and the data file:

```
date    state
2014-May-12 task1
2014-May-25 task2
2014-Jun-28 tsak3
```

NOTICE:The tsv file should separate its every datum by tab,assure that your paste code doesn`t change that,that may cause a fail reading.

I kown the skill like:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
read.onload=...
```

but I don`t kown what to do in my situation.

Comment: `d3.tsv` is an asynchronous call -- everything you want to do with the data needs to happen in the callback function.

Comment: @LarsKothoff NO,it`s doesn`t help,you put a console.log(total) after and outside the d3.tsv() call,it will also so you a 0 in the console.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying. Put this code *inside* the callback.

Comment: I kown you mean put everything in the callback,but I want to known is there any solution to put outside the callback function.

Comment: No. It's an asynchronous call.

Comment: using [queue.js](https://github.com/mbostock/queue) could be an option?

Comment: @LarsKothoff OK,I`m stop being stubborn:)I will learn something about asynchromnous call,Thanks,I`ll leave my post here to see is there any new info from others,in that way,I can learn something more:)Thanks.

Comment: @d3noob I post the question just because I want to learn something from this,if I use a skill like changing another library would leave me with confuse about the same situation when I meet it again:)I`m a noob for web development,thanks as well for your comment.

Comment: No problem. I struggled with the concept of synchronous and asynchronous events for longer than I care to admit. We learn by doing. Kudos to you for getting out and doing :-).

Comment: Reading the comments I guess my answer is not helpful but this part may explain why you cannot do that: Javascript is an asynchronized language so the callback function doesn't block the rest of code from running, or in other words the javascript engine starts a new thread that loads the data file and when it is done runs the callback, while the code right after the call back is running in parallel. Since loading data.tsv file needs I/O operations the lines after the callback actually run before the callback function and by that time your array is still empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest fix is to move the total calculation inside the tsv callback function.

```
d3.tsv("data.tsv",function(error,data){
     for(var i in data) {

                    ...

     }        
     var total = 0;

     for(var i in dataset){
         total =total + dataset[i].elapse;
     }

     console.log(total);
});
```

Note that Javascript is an asynchronized language so the callback function doesn't block the rest of code from running, and since loading data.tsv file needs I/O operations the lines after the callback actually run before the callback function and by that time your array is still empty.